# How to make distance for moving image in html5

Tags: html, css

This is what I tried:

css code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
#animate-area { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 2538px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    background-image: url('http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png');
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
/* Put your css in here */
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
```

Now what I need, every once rotational completed, then again start to move from right to left. I need some distance for every rotational completed.

Can somebody help to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/6d6xa65n/4/

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/6d6xa65n/4/ (I shortened animation time also to see what is happenig faster).

Comment: No I don't think I understand what you mean by "distance" maybe this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6d6xa65n/5/ ?

Comment: still i confused, when background-image: url('http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png'); got right solution, when background-image: url('../img/banner.png'); got something different, that is next rotation again start from left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any delay between iterations in css3 other than animation-delay, which is used at the beginning, however you can use jQuery for delay. For direction from right to left change:

```
 animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite alternate;
 -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite  alternate;
 -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite alternate;
```

If you want to add delay change to:

```
 animation: animatedBackground 40s 5s linear infinite alternate;
 -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s 5s linear infinite  alternate;
 -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s 5s linear infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s 5s linear infinite alternate;
```

Or add this, which will give you a delay at the end and beginning if you mean delay by "distance":

```
    background-image: url('http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png');
    animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
/* Put your css in here */
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { left: 0; }
    25% { left: 0; }
    50% {left: -2000px;}
    100% { left: -2000px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { left: 0; }
    25% { left: 0; }
    50% {left: -2000px;}
    100% { left: -2000px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { left: 0; }
    25% { left: 0; }
    50% {left: -2000px;}
    100% { left: -2000px; }
}
```